# Stop relaunch of android app when return from browser to app

Tags: android, webview

I am developing app in android webview.

In my application, i have one button which redirect user to browser. So what i want is on return from browser to my application, app should not relaunch. It should just come in foreground.

Comment: Define the term "relaunch".

Comment: relaunch means application is starting again as if we click on app icon at initial time... And as i am working with webview, there is only one activity, but what i want to do is on return back from browser to app, it should display last html visited page not first html page in webview.....

Comment: When navigating back from the browser with the "back"-button, it should do exactly that. How are you "getting back"?

Comment: Actually i am not using back button for return. In my application, i am performing login in browser and as soon as login is completed, user is redirect back to app from browser. For that i am using url scheme..like window.open("Myapp://abc.com/1223"); And in my mainactivity i have a intent-filter which contain this url scheme...

Comment: I see, two options: Call an Activity that represents the "starting point" you which **or** Put the login in your WebView, too.